# python object member refer to itself incorrectly

Tags: python

I was tring to build a trie tree base on a word list, below is the node class defintion, self.next_trees for children of the node.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, charactor, tree_dict={}):
        self.charactor = charactor
        self.next_trees = tree_dict
        self.is_end = False
```

and build the tree use this function

```
def build_tree(words):
    root = Node(None)
    for word in words:
        trace = root.next_trees
        for i,c in enumerate(word):
            if c not in trace:
                trace[c] = Node(charactor=c)

                pdb.set_trace()

                if i == len(word)-1:
                    trace[c].is_end = True
                else:
                    trace = trace[c].next_trees
            else:
                trace = trace[c].next_trees
return root
```

each time when the codes run to the break point, the object "trace" refers to is exactly the same object "trace[c].next_trees" refer to,rather than a empty dict"{}" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tea3Z.png)

and I copy similiar codes to a new .py file and run, it won't happen again.why it happens here?(python version 2.7.12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a mutable object as a default variable (`tree_dict={}`). Try doing this instead:

```
def __init__(self, charactor, tree_dict=None):
    if tree_dict is None:
        tree_dict = {}
```

The default value of `tree_dict` (`{}`) is evaluated only when the `__init__` method is constructed, *not* when it is called. This default value is then stored and reused for every future call to `__init__`. This then means that *all* instances of `Node` initialized with no explicit value of `tree_node` will use this stored object as its `tree_node`, meaning that when you modify one, you modify all others as well.